# Nativescript - How to not show the crash log in apllication?

Tags: nativescript, production-environment

I'm preparing my app to publish on the play store but there's just one thing that I'm not able to do yet. When the application crashes, a screen appears with two tabs: Exception and Logcat. THis is fine during development but in production version, I don't want users to see this screen when app crashes (If it crashes :p ). How can I remove it?

Comment: If you run the build command with the `--release` flag, the exception screen wouldn't be shown to the users. There is a [nice article](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/steps-to-publish-your-nativescript-app-to-the-app-stores) about preparing your app for release.

Comment: I'm using Sidekick and I toggled the switch to release build. I beleive thats the equivalent of `--release` flag. But the exceptions screen still shows.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of NativeScript (4.2.2) has introduced a flag that can disable the auto caching of errors. Detailed information can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/error-handling#disabling-exceptions-auto-catching).

Example for using the falg to stop propagating the errors:
***app/package.json***

```
{
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "name": "tns-template-hello-world-ts",
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "discardUncaughtJsExceptions":true
}
```

> Note: Enabling this property can lead to discarding an exception,
>   which can lead to unexpected application behaviours. For the proper
>   exception handling, it is recommended to keep auto cathing enabled.